# Cleaner way to convert array of nullable datetime to nullable double?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

I have a:

```
DateTime?[] dates
```

I need to convert to:

```
Double?[] oaDates
```

Any way to clean up this one liner? Or should I just resort to a function?

```
DateTime?[] dates = new DateTime?[]{DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)}; //example array
Double?[] oaDates = dates.Select(t => (t==null)?((double?)null):(t??DateTime.MinValue).ToOADate()).ToArray();
```

I can't call a method on t without checking that it's null (hence the tertiary operator) and I have to coalesce it as well so that I can call OADate (hence the coalesce and filler DateTime.MinValue that will never be hit).

It gets the job done in one line, but it is looking a little perl-like.

Maybe an extension method? That way I can hide the ugliness and just do something along the lines of:

```
dates.ToNullableOADates();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually call extension methods on `null` references.  So you could define an extension method to convert a single `DateTime?` to a `double?` like:

```
public static class DateUtil
{
    public static double? ConvertToDouble(this DateTime? date)
    {
        return date.HasValue ? date.Value.ToOADate() : (double?)null;
    }
}
```

Then call it like:

```
double?[] oaDates = dates.Select(t => t.ConvertToDouble()).ToArray();
```

However, you could equally call it using the method group syntax:

```
double?[] oaDates1 = dates.Select(DateUtil.ConvertToDouble).ToArray();
```

Comment: Great. That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: if you are going this way, call it ToOADate :)

Answer (score 2):

not sure why you have t??

can't you just do...

```
Double?[] oaDates = 
   dates.Select(t => (t == null) ? (double?)null : t.Value.ToOADate()).ToArray();
```

Comment: I honestly didn't know about the Value property (now I do thanks). Without it I needed the null-coalescing operator (??).

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = dates.Select(t => t.HasValue ? t.Value.ToOADate() : (double?)null).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 dates.Select( t=> t==default(DateTime?) || t.HasValue==false ? (double?)(null):t.Value.ToOADate() ).ToArray()
```